# set path in rstudio

Tags: r

Can anyone please guide me setting up the path in rstudio, why I cant change present working directory. what if I want to save a file on desktop and pull up the file in Rstudio.

Your help is appreciated.

thanks, sandy

Comment: `setwd()` to set and `getwd()` to check

Comment: Also, I believe that if you open rstudio by clicking on a .R script, rstudio will use the working directory of that file as the current working directory.

Comment: Hi @Sandeep. Welcome to SO. Saying "Why cannot I change present working directory" is not enough. Please tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the most common reasons I have found where setting directory was a problem with the solution

- Forgot the "" marks around the path example of correct `setwd("Libraries/Documents")`
- Working in Windows and forgot to switch the back-slash to a forward slash, examples: WRONG-> `"Libraries\Documents"` RIGHT->`"Libraries/Documents"`
- There path is on a shared system where they system denies that access (we have remote folders on servers at work that cannot be addressed this way)...IT security
- The directory is not actually mapped as you stated, example possibly you do not need the `Libraries` part or you have to expressly include another level of folders above your current address
- The directory has a different name, a capital letter, a space in it or something making addressing it on your system difficult
- You are actually already in the wanted directory. as joel said, try `getwd()` to see where it says you are.

If none of this is your problem, post the error message and your system (linux, OS10.?, Windows 7 pro) and they `setwd("path_to_stuff")` you are using and we can try to get to the heart of the matter better.